# Row count of table of active workbook.worksheet table

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for the proper syntax to return the row count of a table within a workbook.worksheet.  Found this code and need help with syntax: "Getting Object variable or with block variable not set."

I am attempting to validate if the table contains data and if not rerun the update code.  if there is a better way feel free to make suggestions.

Thanks.

```
    nRows = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ResPlan_Data").ListObjects("Res_Plan_Data").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count


                        nRows = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ResPlan_Data").ListObjects("Res_Plan_Data").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
                        If nRows = 0 And Range("A3").Select <> Null Then
                            Range("A3").Select
                            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
                            Selection.Copy
                            Range("Res_Plan_Data[ResourceFile]").Select
                            ActiveSheet.Paste
                        ElseIf nRows = 0 And Range("A3").Select = Null Then
                            If Worksheets("Resplan_Data").Visible = True Or Worksheets("ProjSum").Visible = True Then
                                Worksheets("Resplan_Data").Visible = False
                                Worksheets("ProjSum").Visible = False
                                Worksheets("Data Input").Select
                                MsgBox "Re-Select the Update Data Button, to re-processed missing data", vbOKOnly
                                Exit Function
                            End If
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sende. (1) `Range("A3").Select` can only return `True` or `False` and `True <> Null` as much as `False <> Null` will return `Null`. So, non of your `If` statements will work and the entire code within never be executed. (2) You repeat the same row twice `nRows = ....`. (3) There is an `End If` missing after the last line. That will take care of your error. But the code will execute without doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion, however, I decided to eliminate that portion of the code and went with the closing & reopening of the of the original workbook, and this made the above code not necessary.